# I can't download classes and triggers in Eclipse

Tags: ide, metadata, mavensmate

I wanrt to download my project metadata in Eclipse also in Mavensmate IDE. The problem is that in metadata project component apex classes and Triggers does not appear.Do I need to change something in configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have no custom classes nor triggers, these folders would appear empty. In MavensMate, the directories for classes and triggers do not appear at all when there are no triggers or classes in the org.

Comment: Hi, but in my org I have more tan 15 classes and many triggers too, I don't know if is a permissions issue.

Comment: Are those triggers and classes part of managed packages?

Comment: What does your package.xml file look like?

Comment: I cloned my System Administrator profile as new and it was assigned to me and everything works again, it was a kind of permission, I steel looking to post the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

try to check System Permissions for your profile.

**Author Apex   - Create Apex classes and triggers** should be enabled.